# How to add choice to Question model by login User

Tags: python, django

I'm learning django i had an idea to modify poll app from django tutorial. I wanted to add possibility to register and login and then i wanted to do a form where user could create a question and add choices. Firstly i tried to make it on one view, but i thought there will be a problem becouse i heve choice and question in separate models. Then i tried to make one vReverse for 'createChoice' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: `['polls\\/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)\\/choice$']iew for creating question and one for creating Choices, but here i've got this error:` 
I would like to ask for some advice on how to do it. It would be great if i could do it in one page.

Here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
from django.contrib import auth
# Create your models here.

User = auth.get_user_model()

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text

class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

app_name = 'pollapp'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('createdPolls/', views.ListView.as_view(), name='createdPolls'),
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
    path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('createPoll/', views.CreatePoll.as_view(), name='createPoll'),
    path('<int:pk>/choice', views.CreateChoicePoll.as_view(), name='createChoice')
]
```

views.py

```
class CreatePoll(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.CreatePollForm
    template_name = 'polls/createPoll.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('pollapp:createChoice')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        poll = form.save(commit=False)
        poll.author = self.request.user
        poll.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

class CreateChoicePoll(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.CreateChoiceForm
    template_name = 'polls/createChoice.html'
    success_url = 'pollapp:index'
```

forms.py

```
class CreatePollForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ('question_text',)

class CreateChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('choice_text',)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a value for the `pk` in the view. You can do that by overriding the [**`.get_success_url(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url):

```
from django.urls import reverse

class CreatePoll(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    form_class = forms.CreatePollForm
    template_name = 'polls/createPoll.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = poll = form.save(commit=False)
        poll.author = self.request.user
        poll.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('pollapp:createChoice', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```